# Android, Logcat window has vanished

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I was using the Logcat window to debug my app, and in order to improve the size of the window, I dragged it onto the windows taskbar to detach it, as per any Eclipse panel.

Now though, when I go to the DDMS perspective and click *Window-->Show View-->Logcat*, I don't get the Logcat window at all.

I've tried restarting Eclipse, and minimized everything in the hope that the Logcat window would be there, but there's nothing.

Anybody else had any experience like this?

Comment: Does the logcat window show up in the Java perspective?

Comment: Hi Ted, nope, it's not even an option from the "Window-->Show View" menu bar (in the Java perspective), it IS an option from the DDMS perspective, but just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, in the Java view you need to open "Window->Show View->Other...".

Comment: Hi Ted, that had a similar effect to just clicking "Window-->Show View-->Logcat", in that nothing happened. Thanks for the advice, the "Reset" option fro Aaron (below) did the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try right clicking on the DDMS perspective button and selecting "Reset".

After clicking on the DDMS perspective button. Right-click and then select "Reset".

Comment: Bingo !, we have a winner. Thanks Aaron, I'm not even going to wonder why it vanished, just glad it's back. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It might have got minimized(I don't exactly get what you mean by "minimized everything and tried").

If you are using mac, an icon like [image: this] might be there at the bottom right of the window(it appears when it is minimized). Click on that icon and the logcat window should reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on LogCat icon [image: LogCat icon] and uncheck  "Fast View" ,by doing so default settings will be restored.it worked for me ..